# Usage of "go about"

Tags: phrase-usage, phrasal-verbs

[**Explanations of go about something**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/go+about)

## 1. to approach the doing of something in a particular way

> > How should I go about researching this topic?
> >
> > Would you tell me how to go about it?

## 2. to do something

> > We'd like to help but we're not sure how to go about it.
> >
> > How do you go about getting a visa?

I wonder if we can simply use **"do"** or omit the phrase in these examples instead of using this heavy phrasal verb.

Does it add any extra meaning? Is it intended for written English?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Do* has more of a 'perfective' feel to me than *go about* - you see it from outside, completed, where *go about* is more about engaging in the process. *Go about* is perfectly acceptable in both conversational and formal registers.

*Do VERBing* is not equivalent to *VERB* - it's only idiomatic if *VERBing* is fully  deverbalized, as in "I do a lot of writing" - so you can't use it in 1a or 2b.

Comment: Oh, I don't mean Do VERBing. I mean, say, "How should I research this topic?" I would think it also suggests what the procedures are. (BTW, why are you not sleeping?)

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng Cards-Cubs tied in the 12th inning.

Comment: Come to think of it. All these examples include "how". Is this phrasal verb commonly used only in this way?

Comment: For your examples anyway... If you ask several people how to bake a cake, they will tell you several ways to *go about/do* it. Though in general I would replace "do" with a more descriptive verb where possible.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can on a case by case basis. Either use *do*, or omit *go about*. If you use *do*, in some cases the verb form is changed too.

1a)

> How should I *go about researching* this topic?
>   or
>   How should I *do research on* this topic?

1b)

> Would you tell me how to *go about* it?
>   or
>   Would you tell me how to *do* it?

2a)

> We'd like to help but we're not sure how to *go about* it.
>   or
>   We'd like to help but we're not sure how to *do* it.

2b)

> How do you *go about* getting a visa?
>   or
>   How do you *get* a visa?